# Node.js using Regular Expression to extract certain string from the response

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, extract, information-retrieval

I want to use regex to extract some text from the website html code i've retrieved by using the Nodejs. And the text i received was like this:

```
<body>

...

<p>text with certain format that I want.</p>

...

</body>
```

How should I extract the test and store it in a variable?

The reason I do this is because I need to retrieve the information from numerous pages, it is impossible to do it manually.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a specific string? Is there more than one paragraph on these pages?

Comment: Use [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - it's a serverside jQuery. Or you could use [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: 1) duplicate 2) don't do it 3) link for both http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1178921

Comment: @deltree one of my favourite posts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the first instance of a paragraph, you can do this, but this will only fetch the content of the first paragraph. If you want a specific paragraph, you need a way to identify that paragraph as opposed to every other one in the HTML.

If you're looking for something more specific, we'll need to know more about what you're trying to do.

```js
var regex = /<p>(.*)?<\/p>/,
    html = [your html here],
    results = regex.exec(html);

console.log(results); // an array of matches
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text= '<p>text with certain format that I want.</p>';
jQuery('<div>' + text + '</div>').text();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: With this "trick" you can clean your response from html tags, or html entities, etc.